# React Native ScreenProps Undefined Function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I can't pass a class method to `screenProps`. In the `AppContainer's screenProps` I'm passing two props `changeModalVisibility` & `thisKeyValueIsDefined` and running a `console.warn` but only `thisKeyValueIsDefined` is showing in the console warn. Trying to use `screenProps.changeModalVisibility(true)` throws and error `Undefined/Not a Function`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

const Home = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => (
  <SafeAreaView>
    <Button
      title="Go to modal"
      onPress={() => console.warn(screenProps)}
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
);

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Home',
    },
  },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppStack);

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  }

  modalChangeVisibility = (modalVisible = false) => {
    this.setState({ modalVisible });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <AppContainer screenProps={{ changeModalVisibility: this.changeModalVisibility, thisKeyValueIsDefined: true, }} />
        <Modal visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.modalContainer}>
            <View style={styles.modalBody}>
              <Text>
                This modal is just an example.
              </Text>
              <Button
                title="Close Modal"
                onPress={() => this.modalChangeVisibility(false)}
              />
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.25)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  modalBody: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: '80%',
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
  }
});
```

Been searching for about 4 hours now and can't find any blog or article about why `changeModalVisibility` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined your function as `modalChangeVisibility` in your `App` component, except when you set it in your screenProps you have called it as `this.changeModalVisibility`.

In the following code I have updated the name and it works.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

const Home = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => (
  <SafeAreaView>
    <Button
      title="Go to modal"
      onPress={() => screenProps.changeModalVisibility(true)}
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
);

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Home',
    },
  },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppStack);

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  }

  modalChangeVisibility = (modalVisible = false) => {
    this.setState({ modalVisible });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <AppContainer screenProps={{ changeModalVisibility: this.modalChangeVisibility, thisKeyValueIsDefined: true, }} />
        <Modal visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.modalContainer}>
            <View style={styles.modalBody}>
              <Text>
                This modal is just an example.
              </Text>
              <Button
                title="Close Modal"
                onPress={() => this.modalChangeVisibility(false)}
              />
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.25)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  modalBody: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: '80%',
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
  }
});
```

[image: modal displaying]

Answer (score 0):

`changeModalVisibility` function is not defined in the `App.js` class. That's why you are getting `undefined`.